# Is it possible to remove an anchor by name?

Tags: javascript, html

I have bought for a customer an extension for Magento and that extension has applied on the code a damn html anchor (the extension has a crypt, so I can't access the code) and I need to remove it. See what I get viewing source code through pressing Ctrl + U:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            Event.observe(window, 'load', function() {
                $('processing-cerebrum-all-observer-AdminhtmlDashboardIndexLicenseProcessor').hide();
                window.location.hash="LicenseExpireChart";
            });
        </script>

        <a name="LicenseExpireChart"></a>
```

This is really annoying me, because I wanna see the top of Dashboard page and after page is loaded it is forced to scroll into the anchor. How can I remove this code completely using javascript/jquery?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answers given above perfectly correct, but there is a better way - vanilla-js:

```
var els = document.getElementsByName('LicenseExpireChart');
for (var i = 0, l = els.length; i < l; i++) { els[i].parentNode.removeChild(els[i]); }
```

[demonstrative evidence](http://jsperf.com/find-and-remove-jquery-vs-vanilla-js)

Comment: Wow, it worked perfectly! I didn't know about vanilla, never heard about it. Thank you!

Comment: [vanilla-js](http://vanilla-js.com/) - is a fast, lightweight, cross-platform framework
for building incredible, powerful JavaScript applications. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('a[name="LicenseExpireChart"]').remove();
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. I will try this, as an alternative of the other answer given. Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

The .remove() method takes elements out of the DOM

```
$('a[name="LicenseExpireChart"]').remove();
```